# TFLite Conversion changing model weights

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, toco

I have a custom built tensorflow graph implementing MobileNetV2-SSDLite which I implemented myself. It is working fine on the PC.

However, when I convert the model to TFLite (all float, no quantization), the model weights are changed drastically.

To give an example, a filter which was initially - 
 0.13172674179077148,
 2.3185202252437188e-32,
 -0.003990101162344217

becomes-
4.165565013885498,
-2.3981268405914307,
-1.1919032335281372

The large weight values are completely throwing off my on-device inferences. Need help! :(

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to convert to tflite? For instance are you using toco, and if so what parameters are you using? While I haven't been looking at the filters, [here are my default instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22106#issuecomment-428409506) for finetuning a MobileNetV2-SSD and SSDLite graphs and the model has been performing well.